# Как установить на событие Звуковой сигнал

Tags: javascript, php, html

Не силен в php, прошу помощи. Нужно сделать чтобы на сайте при появлении текста СЕЙЧАС СМОТРЯТ (он появляется в админ панели, если пользователь зашел на сайт произошел звуковой сигнал, один раз воспроизвёлся звуковой файл). При этом происходит обновление через каждые 5 секунд, нахождение пользователя, то есть при обновлении если повесить функцию, возможно её повторное исполнение через каждые 5 секунд. Как этого избежать?
Ломаю себе голову не один день, прошу помощи.
Код ниже

```html
<div class="metrics_info">

  <?php echo $geo; ?>

  <br>

  <?php if((strtotime($value["date_view"]) + 180) > time()){ ?>
  <span class="online badge-pulse-green-small"></span> сейчас смотрят
  <br>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php if($value["view_page_title"]){ ?>
  <a title="<?php echo $value[" view_page_title "]; ?>" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $value[" view_page_link "]; ?>">
    <?php echo custom_substr($value["view_page_title"],40, "..."); ?>
  </a>
  <?php }else{ ?>
  <a title="<?php echo $value[" view_page_link "]; ?>" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $value[" view_page_link "]; ?>">
    <?php echo custom_substr($value["view_page_link"],40, "..."); ?>
  </a>
  <?php } ?>



</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/how-to-play-audio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете добавить определение функции `beep`, и если нужно проиграть звук, добавьте в вывод страницы `<script>beep()</script>`.

```html
<!-- Добавить этот код один раз на страницу -->
<script>
const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.audioContext);

/**
 * @param {number} duration Длительность воспроизведения звука 
 * @param {number} frequency Частота звука 
 * @param {number} volume Громкость воспроизведения звука 
 * @param {string} type Тип осцилятора
 * @param {function} callback Функция асинхронного возврата 
 */
function beep(duration, frequency, volume, type, callback) {
    var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
    var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();

    oscillator.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

    if (volume){gainNode.gain.value = volume;}
    if (frequency){oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;}
    if (type){oscillator.type = type;}
    if (callback){oscillator.onended = callback;}

    oscillator.start(audioCtx.currentTime);
    oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + ((duration || 500) / 1000));
};
</script>

<!-- А этот код можно использовать много раз -->
<script>
beep()
</script>

   <button onclick="beep()"> Play </button>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29641185/14255891)

Comment: В принципе понятно, а как сменить звук на свой ? не могу найти !

Comment: Аа, ну это секвенсер, сменой частоты можно добиваться интересных звуков. Например, кнопки тонального номеронабирателя на телефоне выдают звуки частот: `1`= 700/ 900
`2` = 700/ 1100
`3`= 900/ 1100
`4`= 700/ 1300
`5`= 900/ 1300
`6`= 1100/ 1300
`7`= 700/ 1500
`8`= 900/ 1500
`9`= 1100/ 1500
`0`= 1300/ 1500
`#` = 700/ 1700
`*` = 1300/ 1700

Comment: Работает только в такой последовательности  сейчас смотрят<script>beep()</script><button onclick="beep()"> Play </button>, но происходит обновление данных о находящемся пользователе на сайте каждые 5 секунд, И через каждые 5 секунд происходит звук !! Как решить это не понимаю

Comment: Хотелось бы рассмотреть вариант с персональными звуками в виде mp3 для оповещения. Вариант ваш работает но что то не так, в вызове функции.

Comment: прошу прощения за поздний ответ, `<button>play</button>` не надо включать в выдачу, эта кнопка для проигрывания звука чтобы потестить сам звук. А вот `<script>beep()</script>` будет проигрывать звук моментально как только браузер доходит до парсинга/выполения скрипта. Если нужен mp3 там нужна другая стратегия. `<script>new Audio('https://domain.ru/file.mp3').play()</script>`. Просто добавьте это в выдачу поменяв URLдо файла. Для этого предварительных скриптов не нужно. Тогда стоит учитывать, что звук из отдельного файла будет воспроизводиться не сразу, а после загрузки mp3-файла

Comment: Да, это получилось всё !, огромное спасибо Вам ! Но теперь борюсь над проблемой, происходит обновление каждые 5сек. и автоматом запускает сигнал, ломаю голову дальше над этим, как сделать только один раз проигрывание файла при существующей проверке через каждые 5сек.

Comment: Нужно как-то идентифицировать каждый заход. Присваивать каждому пользователю номер либо, использовать идентификатор сессии. Либо как вариант можно ожидать пустую страничку и воспроизводить звук только после того как она опустела и снова пополнилась. В любом случае, тут необходимо больше информации о том как этот механизм работает. Представленного вами кода не достаточно чтобы принимать архитектурные решения. Но в любом случае, это довольно поостая задача для PHP.